# Prevent iFrame src from being triggered as clicked when loads

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following banner iFrame on my page:

```
<iframe name="myname" src="http://sample.com/script/?..." width="320" height="50" ...></iframe>
```

I have some tracking metadata on my page. When this page loads on **iOS** webview and it loads the iFrame src, the tracker immediately shows as if there was a click on that banner. Is there anyway to prevent it from happening either with JS or iFrame's sandbox or some other way?

Comment: Is the tracker capturing that the iframe was clicked or that content inside was clicked? Is the tracker running on the outer page or the loaded page inside the iframe?

Comment: Are you sure that its not just caching and that you haven't clicked on it before?

Comment: @Anthony The tracker runs on the page that contains the iframe. It catches a click when the iframe src is loaded.

Comment: @Dave Yes, positive. The no one clicked the iframe itself.

Comment: How do you know the loaded page isn't triggering the click?

Comment: @Anthony There's nothing on that page that can trigger it. And again, it happens only in iOS webview, not on Android or desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap a div with the iframe and use this code.

```
$('#wrap').click(function() {
  $('#myname').attr('src', function (i, val) {return val;});
});
```

Comment: Is there a jQuery-less solution for that? We just don't use it here, pure JS only...